# Intersection of countable many sets of measure $1$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(X,\mathscr M,\mu)$ and a collection of measurable sets $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\mu (A_n)=1$ for every $n$. Then I don't unterstand the following result:
$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)=1$$

Any idea about it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @faircointossing: My bad, I didn't realise it was a probability space and not a general measure space.

Comment: What's the measure of the complement of $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n$?

Comment: Ok the measure of the complement is $\mu\left(\bigcup X\setminus A_n\right)=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each set $A_n$ has very small complement, since this is occurring in a probability space - namely, $A_n^c$ has measure exactly $0$. Now by additivity of a measure,

$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n^c\right) \le \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n^c) = 0$$

Now apply De Morgan's.

---

Morally, each $A_n$ fills up *almost* the entire space, except for some tiny little mass that the measure can't even detect. Hence, the intersection of all these sets contains almost everything again.