# Sequence converging in probability and also almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**Context**: It is known that convergence a.s. implies convergence in probability. Could the converse be true with additional assumptions? I would like to understand if the proof of the following lemma (that I invented) is correct. If the proof is wrong, could the lemma be correct by other reasons ?

**Lemma**: We are given a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging in probability to $X$. If for every $\epsilon>0$,  $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=O(1/n^2)$ than $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$.

Proof of lemma:

We observe that:

$\sum_n P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) <\infty $

Therefore by the Borel-Cantelli lemma:

$P(\limsup_n \{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\})=0$

This says that fixed $\epsilon$, there is only a set of zero measure such that $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$ happens (i.e. it is satisfied) infinite times. Told another way, almost surely the condition $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$ is satisfied only for a finite number of $n$.

Take now $\epsilon_k=1/k$ and $A_k$ the set where  $|X_n-X|>\epsilon_k$ is satisfied only for a finite number of $n$. We just proved that  $P(A_k)=1$. Now take:

$A\equiv\cap_{k\ge 1} A_k$

By this [Intersection of countable many sets of measure $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872119/intersection-of-countable-many-sets-of-measure-1) we can deduce that $\mu(A)=1$. Elements belonging to $A$ satisfy the definition for convergence, therefore the lemma is proven.

Does it make sense?

Comment: In general "summable convergence in probability for every $\epsilon$", i.e. $\sum_n P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\infty$ for every $\epsilon>0$, implies a.s. convergence. The argument uses the Borel-Cantelli lemma as you say here.

Comment: Thank you ! You may also want to check the second part of this reasoning: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212097/sequence-converging-in-probability-has-always-a-subsequence-converging-almost-su